# Laravel - Get belongsTo relationship without id using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm using `laravel` 7.30, I have a post model linked to user model with belongsTo relationship, I want to retrieve all posts with user property that contains only the name of the user for api purposes.

what i've tried so far.

```php
public function index()
{
    return Post::with('user:id,name')->get();
}
```

but the result of this code is a nested object 'user' which has 2 fields id and name on each post, I only want a single field with posts fields called user which has the name only and not a nested object for api purposes.

I've made it using database query builder, but i'm looking for a way using Eloquent

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `Post` Model:

```
protected $appends = [
    "author_name"
];

public function getAuthorNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->name;
}
```

This will make sure the user's name is appended to the `Post` object every time it is being called.

Then from your controller, you can easily do this:

```
public function index()
{
    return Post::get();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, But still includes the user object, So I had to hide it using the hidden array on the post model, Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help Zakaria Benali . Kindly upvote my answer 

Comment: Done ! , Does this method works for the nested relationships ? for example post with comments can u get a comment with username with the same method

Comment: Yes, it works for nested relationships also, you just have to add the same `getAuthorNameAttribute()` on the `Comment` model also. You have not upvoted yet...kindly use the arrow pointing up on the answer to upvote

Comment: I did upvote but it seems that i have to reach 15 reputations for it to show on posts, i get this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."